# HTML/JSX not showing up

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

[image]
i'm rendering a component Purchase with text "Purchase Product", when I click a button on my navigation bar. The text "Purchase Product" can only be seen when i put it in the  navigation tag (image 1 and 2) [image]

however, i want this text to only be seen outside of the navigation bar. so i moved it outside the  navigation tag. But the "Purchase Product" cannot be seen. It is in the space below the navigation bar but just not showing up. My font colour is black and should be showing. (image 3 and 4)  [image] [image]

This is my Purchase component that i wish to render
[image]
Please help me!! thank you

Comment: Need more info, but I was able to re-create your problem [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-3okgku?file=src/App.js) and as you can see, it's working. Feel free to edit the changes and try to re-create your issue.

Comment: Thank you for the help. It was something to do with my inline css. yours work perfectly!